# Simple XMLHttpRequest function to return a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to return a json object following an XMLHttpRequest get request, and I come up short. I think that might be because it is asynchronous, but I really can't put my finger on how to make it work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var apiEndpoint = 'http://someapiendpoint.com/'

//Helpers
function sendRequest(_path) {
  var results =  {}
  req = new XMLHttpRequest()
  req.open('GET', apiEndpoint+_path)
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      results = JSON.parse(this.response)
    }
  }
  req.send()
  return results
}

// Action
console.log(sendRequest('client1/'))

}); // end document ready
```

Comment: Asynchronous call mate, console.log will only get you `{}`

Comment: mmm okay so if I do `req.open('GET', apiEndpoint+_path, false)` it works... but I guess that is also block the execution, right?

Comment: u are trying to return results which isn't yet ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this construction

```
function sendRequest(_path, cb) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.open('GET', apiEndpoint+_path);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        cb(JSON.parse(this.response));
    }
    else{
        cb(null);
    }
}
    req.send();
}

// Action
sendRequest('client1/', function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

For asynchronous calls you need to use call backs

Comment: Thanks, got me up and running! For ref. this also helped me a bunch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var apiEndpoint = 'http://someapiendpoint.com/';

   function sendRequest(path, callback){
      $.get(apiEndpoint+path, function(response){
          callback(JSON.parse(response));
      }, json).fail(function(){
          console.log('Failed');
      });
   }

   sendRequest('client1/', function(json){
       if(json){
           console.log(json);
       }
   });
});
```